# How to insert number from this code into php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert the number only from this:

```
<span class="fb-comments-count" data-href="http://example.com/"></span>comments
```

into some existing php code:

```
<span class="meta_facebook_comments">
   <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> 
        <?php 
            echo "Comments";
        ?>
</span>
```

and for the love of life I can't figure it out?

i.e. to display something like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-comments"></i> 2 Comments
```

for example..

looking for some advice,
Thanks

Comment: you need list of numbers of just 1 entry/row?

Comment: Are you getting values within your PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery `prepend` to add value before "comments" text:

```
$(".fa .fa-comments").prepend("2 ");
```

The results will be

> 2 comments

**EDIT**: based of OP's comment-> to transfer data from one element to another, use this method:

```
var number_of_comments = $(".fb-comments-count").text(); //get number of comments  
$(".fa .fa-comments").prepend(number_of_comments); //add comment count to another element
```

Please see this working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Luthando/ozouzwzb)

Comment: I mean how do add that class in prepend?

Comment: <span class="fb-comments-count" data-href="http://example.com/"></span>comments retrieves the number of facebook comments, I'd like to use that number and echo it to echo "Comments";

Comment: thanks but the number is hard coded? the number must come from <span class="fb-comments-count" data-href="http://example.com/"></span>comments

Comment: @Hopelessone please check the demo carefully, the number comes from this element `<span class="fb-comments-count" data-href="http://example.com/" style="display:none;">1</span>`